# ASP:PlaceHolder - can't find code that's generating its contents

Tags: asp.net

I need to update a bit of text that's being rendered on a .aspx page.  I've searched the source and DB tables, views, and stored procedures, and can't find it.

The bit of code that's generating the text looks like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="teamMemberTable" runat="server" />
```

I searched and couldn't find any references to `teamMemberTable` anywhere else in the code.  Is it possible that the code generating that bit has been compiled into binary and doesn't exist in plaintext anymore?

Here is an example of the outputted html:

```
<span id="ctl00_rightContent_Repeater1_ctl01_Literal1" class="teamListName">
    Team Number One
</span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="teamListMember">Team Captian</td>
        <td class="teamListPlayer">Jane Doe</td>
        <td class="teamListStatus teamListStatusPaid">Paid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="teamListMember">Player 2</td>
        <td class="teamListPlayer">John Q. Public</td>
        <td class="teamListStatus teamListStatusNotPaid">Not Paid</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do we get to guess what kind of content it was?

Comment: show us what and how it was rendered and what do you need from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that the code is in an assembly that has already been compiled and is not in plaintext. One option is to run a tool such as .NET Reflector or ILSpy and decompiling all the assemblies in the app and searching through the decompiled code to locate any references to "teamMemberTable".

Another possibility is that the control is being referenced by index instead of by name. For example, if the PlaceHolder control is in the page, it could be referenced as `Page.Controls[5]` and so you'd never see the name in the source code.